# Execute open New Window and Execute Javascript

Tags: javascript

Good Day!

is it possible when i open new window from parent window, a javascript will execute on the new WINDOW?

Like for example if the new window completely load, a textfield will change a value.

Thanks

Comment: Scripts should be able to interact between parent and child window as long as both window is on the exact same host name.

Comment: Yes.. it the same domain and host.. how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

get the parameter from new window onLoad() event to parent window, notifying that new window has been load.

I hope this will solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for *putting* a function in a child window then let the child window runs it. The `showTitle` function will simply show the current document title. The child page will wait for a specific function and calls it when it *arrives*.

parent.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>parent</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function showTitle() {
 alert('Page Title = '+this.document.title);
}
function childLoaded() {
 showTitle();
 var childWnd=document.getElementById('fchild').contentWindow;
 if (!childWnd) return;
 childWnd.newFunc=showTitle;
}
</script>
parent<br />
<iframe id=fchild src="child.html" width=300 height=300 onload="childLoaded()"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

child.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>child</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var waiter,newFunc=null;
function waitFunc() {
 if (newFunc) {
  clearInterval(waiter);
  newFunc();
 }
}
waiter=setInterval(waitFunc, 1000);
</script>
child
</body>
</html>
```